# I can't handle ArithmeticException

Tags: java

I tried to handle **ArithmeticException** by throwing an exception in the method and by handling with **try** and **catch** block in the caller method. But the program still shows ArithmeticException error.

```
import java.util.Scanner;  
public class QuotientWithException{
   public static int quotient(int n1,int n2){
      if(n2==0)
        throw new ArithmeticException("Divisor cannot be zero");
      return n1/n2;
   }
   public static void main(String[] args){
      Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.print("Enter two integers:");
      int n1=input.nextInt();
      int n2=input.nextInt();
      
      try{
          int result=quotient(n1,n2);
          System.out.println(n1+"/"+n2+" is "+result);
      }
      catch(ArithmeticException ex){
          System.out.println("Exception: an integer cannot be divided by zero");
      }
      System.out.println("Execution continues ...");
   }
}
```

**Input**

```
Enter two Integers:3 0
```

**Output**

```
Thread [main] (Suspended (exception ArithmeticException)) (out of synch)    
QuotientWithException.main(String[]) line: 19 (out of synch)
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "But the program still shows ArithmeticException error"?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this in Java 11. I get `Exception: an integer cannot be divided by zero Execution continues ...`

Comment: How are you running this? From an IDE (if yes, which one and how)? From the command line (if yes, with what command)?

Comment: Consider renaming the title to something like "Thread [main] (Suspended (exception ArithmeticException))", since this is unrelated to your actual exception, but is related to the keyword "Suspended".

Comment: btw, nicely done on the first question! clear, without useless commentary, with a small amount of code, input, expected and actual outputs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Suspended" implies you're running your code using a debugger or similar functionality that is catching the exception and suspending the program run. If you run your code without a debugger, it should work as expected.